# Reading 2-different columns from a file in C and storing them in 2 different arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I am not so familiar with File Handling in C. I have a .txt file which contains something like this:

```
135.33208225150605 OK
165.1233490789463 OK
245.2329542568199 OK
301.9041144959863 D
```

I want to store column with numbers in an double array and the string column in another string array.

I did something like this:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("protocol1QT.seq", "r");
int i;
for(i=0;i<=148;i++){

    fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);
    char *buffcopy = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
    if(buffcopy == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); exit(1); }
    strcpy(buffcopy, buff);
    line[i] = buffcopy;
    }

   fclose(fp);
```

It reads perfectly fine but how do i make to read separately and store in 2 different arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("protocol1QT.seq", "r");
int i;
double dv;

for(i=0;i<=148 && fscanf(fp, "%lf %[^\n]", &dv, buff)==2;i++){
    char *buffcopy = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
    if(buffcopy == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); exit(1); }
    strcpy(buffcopy, buff);
    string_array[i] = buffcopy;//char *string_array[149];
    numbers[i] = dv;           //double numbers[149];
}
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either separate it with `strtok()` or if it's just this simple case use `sscanf()` like this

```
char text[10]; // more if it could be larger
float number;
if (sscanf(line, "%f%9s", &number, text) == 2)
    process_columns(number, text);
```

Also: Check `fp` for `NULL` before `fgets()` and put `fgets()` in the `for` condition.